# Аналог Pythonовского numpy.linspace в qt c++

Tags: python, c++, qt, qt5, c++17

Собственно, есть команда на Python:

```
x = np.linspace(0, l, N + 1)
```

Как её переписать на Qt\C++?

Comment: Для не умеющих в исходный язык (питон), лучше вкратце объяснять, что делает функция.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Функция linspace() возвращает одномерный массив из указанного количества элементов, значения которых равномерно распределенны внутри заданного интервала.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такая функция легко пишется "на коленке". Где то так

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<double> linspace(double start, double end, int count)
{
    std::vector<double> r;
    r.reserve(count);
    double step = (end - start) / (count-1);
    for (int i = 0; i < count ; i++) {
        r.push_back(start + i * step);
    }
    return r;
}

int main()
{
    auto v = linspace(0,1,11);
    for (auto a : v) {
        std::cout << a << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Огроменное спасибо